# Why RewriteRule isn't working on my wamp?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

**.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/category/([0-9]+)/?$ /category.php?category_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I put the file in:
localhost/.htaccess

"category.php" page is in:
localhost/website/category.php

I tried:
localhost/website/category/4/

But it said:

> The requested URL
>   /website/public/category/5/ was not
>   found on this server.

BTW, I tested .htaccess with another simpler rule and it was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the pattern matching and automatically *added* after the substitution has been done.

So in case of the document root directory, remove the leading `/` from the pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/?$ /category.php?question_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Secondly, since your base path is actually `/website/` and not `/`, change the base path with `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteBase /website/
```

Note that this base path applies to all rules in this .htaccess file. So you rather might want to change just the particular rules, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^website/category/([0-9]+)/?$ /website/category.php?question_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Deleting mine. This answer explains it way better.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, thankx a lot Gumbo, it worked :). Thanks a lot for you too Vivin. :)